# Map different function to first and last element in list

Tags: list, f#

I have a function where I want to transform a list of floats into another one, where for each element I want to have x percent of element i spill over into element i + 1

example:

```
let p3 = [0.1; 0.2; 0.4; 0.2; 0.1]
```

then p3_s should be:

```
[0.05; 0.15; 0.3; 0.3; 0.2]
```

To do this I took half of each element and added it to the next element.

- 0.1 became 0.05 because it gave 0.05 to the next, there is no previous element
- 0.2 became 0.15 because it gave 0.1 to the next and got 0.05 from the
  first
- etc
- and finally 0.1 became 0.2 because it .01 from the
  previous. There is no next element.

Now I came up with this which works but only for list of size 5:

```
// create list
let p3 = [0.1; 0.2; 0.4; 0.2; 0.1]

let shiftList orgList shift =    

    // chop list up in tuples of what stays and what moves
    let ms = orgList |> List.map (fun p-> (p * shift, p * (1.0-shift))) 

    // map new list 
    ms |> List.mapi (fun i (move, stay) -> 
        match i with 
        | 0 -> stay
        | 4 -> stay + fst ms.[i-1] + move // note hardcoded 4
        | _ -> stay + fst ms.[i-1])

// get shifted list
shiftList p3 0.5
```

Now for the questions:

1) How do I make it match on any length list? Now I hardcoded the 4 in the match expression but I'd like to be able to accept any lenght list.

I tried this:

```
let shiftList orgList shift =    

    // chop list up in tuples of what stays and what moves
    let ms = orgList |> List.map (fun p-> (p * shift, p * (1.0-shift))) 

    // find length 
    let last = orgList.Length - 1

    // map new list 
    ms |> List.mapi (fun i (move, stay) -> 
        match i with 
        | 0     -> stay
        | last  -> stay + fst ms.[i-1] + move 
        | _     -> stay + fst ms.[i-1]) // now this one will never be matched
```

But this will not treat `last` as the number 4, instead it becomes a variable for `i` even though `last` is already declared above.

So how could I match on a variable, so that I can treat the last elmement differently? Finding the first one is easy because it's at 0.

2) How would you do this? I'm still pretty fresh to F# there are many things I don't know about yet. Guess the general case here is: how do I map a different function to the first and last element of a list, and a general one to the others?

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
let shiftList orgList shift =    

    // chop list up in tuples of what stays and what moves
    let ms = orgList |> List.map (fun p-> (p * shift, p * (1.0-shift))) 

    // find length 
    let last = orgList.Length - 1

    // map new list 
    ms |> List.mapi (fun i (move, stay) -> 
        match i with 
        | 0     -> stay
        | last' when last' = last -> stay + fst ms.[i-1] + move 
        | _     -> stay + fst ms.[i-1]) // now this one will never be matched
```

Comment: i went with 'x when x = last  ->', is there any special significance to last' ? or is it just a variable name with a ' in it?

Comment: @gjvdkamp there is no significance to the name, although it makes it clear that you are just using it for comparison to the 'real' last variable

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more functional solution

```
let func (input:float list) =
    let rec middle_end input_ =
        match input_ with
        |h::t::[] -> ((h/2.0)+t)::[]
        |h::t::tt ->((h+t)/2.0)::(middle_end (t::tt))
        | _ -> [] //fix short lists
    let fst = input.Head/2.0
    fst::middle_end(input)
```

Also, this only requires a single pass through the list, rather than the 3 in Ramon's solution, as well as less temporary storage.

Comment: hmm I like that. I already accepted Ramon's answer but this seems like a more functional approach to this. Thanks. Actually for my code I switched to an array and did away with any intermediate steps so that should be very quick too. There I do use the 'when' syntax to match the last element.

Comment: Hi thanks again, been playing around with your solution, the fact that you can match deeper an a list than just h::t is quite powerful. Learned a lot today.

Comment: You can write very complicated things in match expressions, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to writing your own recursive function, you can also use built-in functions. The problem can be solved quite easily using `Seq.windowed`. You still need a special case for the last element though:

```
let p3 = [0.1; 0.2; 0.4; 0.2; 0.1] 

// Prefix zero before the list, pre-calculate the length
let p3' = (0.0 :: p3)
let l = p3.Length

// Perform the transformation
p3' 
|> Seq.windowed 2
|> Seq.mapi (fun i ar -> 
    (if i = l - 1 then ar.[1] else ar.[1] / 2.0) + ar.[0] / 2.0)
|> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: Ah.. I did look into Seq.windowed first but got stuck with the first case. Also I didn't know I could use Seq.windowed directly against a list, the Seq.ofList made me leave that path. Thanks, learned some!

Comment: made it into this: |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> v.[0] * shift + v.[1] * (1.0 - if i = last then 0.0 else shift)). Actually like this one best but I don;t like taking answers from someone. I'll wait a little longer next time.

Comment: @gjvdkamp No problem :-) glad it helped - if you're learning functional programming, then writing the recursive version (by _jpalmer_) first is good way to learn core functional concepts. Composing solution from functions that are already in the library (like my or _Ramon_'s solution) is probably the second step.

Comment: I like to not go too overboard with all the functional stuff.. I shy away as soon as it makes me think too hard, I'm into F# mainly for the short syntax for doing this mathy stuff. I promise to give the functional ways some more love in the near future :-) And I do understand jpalmers solution although I wouldn't have come up with that just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using List.scan:

```
let lst = [0.1; 0.2; 0.4; 0.2; 0.1]
let len = (lst.Length-1)

lst 
|> List.mapi (fun i e -> (i,e)) 
|> List.scan (fun (c,_) (i,e) -> if i = len then (0.0,e+c) else ((e/2.0),(e/2.0)+c)) (0.0,0.0) |> List.tail 
|> List.map snd
```

Comment: Took me a second to understand, this is pretty clever too. I was looking for List.unfold where I could push the part that I wanted to shift forward, I guess scan can do just that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea,

```
let bleh p3 =
    match Seq.fold (fun (give,acc) i -> i*0.5,((i*0.5 + give) :: acc)) (0.0,[]) p3 with
    |(give,h::t) -> give+h :: t |> List.rev
    |(_,[]) -> []
```

Comment: It works, but I have no idea how..this is pretty terse ;-) I'll pick it apart when I have time. Thanks!